# Problems integrating maven with gwt in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

When trying to make a gwt web project with maven, I found several errors. For example: "GreetingServiceAsync cannot be resolved to a type" and others. I believe that what I have to do is set the "Goals to run on project import" option in Maven to "process-resources". However, I can't find that textbox in the preferences of my Maven plugin.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Pasting your pom.xml will help to see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when I imported gwt-maven-plugin generated archetype project using Eclipse's import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace. Using import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects instead got rid of the error.

"Goals to run on project import" is in Eclipse's Window > Preferences > Maven.

[image]

If you can't see the the option in Maven preferences, you may have to downgrade you m2eclipse plugin. Old Sonatype m2eclipse at least has it, update site is http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e.